# Back and forth calculation of integer Identifier using bit shifting and OR operations

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, bit

Good morning, don't know if this question is hitting the right StackExchange network. If not please forgive me.

I got an decimal/integer identifier value which i need to split into three separate values. Lets assume we have program ABC. Program ABC is generating the decimal/integer identifier  value using this formula:

```
int identifier = 0;
int unitTypeId = 1;
int boardId = 4;
int messageId = 20;

identifier = (((unitTypeId) << 8) | ((boardId) << 5) | (messageId));
```

`identifier` does now contain a value based on the bit shift and OR operation.

Now we have to develop Program CDE. Program CDE reads out an log file which contains the decimal/integer identifier and some other values which are not necessary for this case. Program CDE has to split the read identifier into the the three values:

```
int unitTypeId = 1;
int boardId = 4;
int messageId = 20;
```

First: Is there a way to achieve this?

My first attempt looks like this, but to be honest i don't get the origin values which the identifier is based on.

```
private void resolveIdentifier()
{
    this.IdentifierBits = Convert.ToString(this.OriginIdentifier, 2); //Convert to binary in a string

    // Message identifiers are constructed:         
    // Unit Type                    Bit 8-10
    // Board ID                     Bit 5-7
    // Unit Specific Message Ids    Bit 0-4

    int[] bits = this.IdentifierBits.PadLeft(11, '0') // Add 0's from left
                     .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())) // convert each char to int
                     .ToArray(); // Convert IEnumerable from select to Array

    Array.Reverse(bits);

    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
    {
        int calcValue = i;
        if (i < 5) // Message Id
        {
            this.MessageId += (int)Math.Pow(2, calcValue);
        }
        else if (i > 4 && i < 8)
        {
            calcValue -= 5;
            this.BoardId += (int)Math.Pow(2, calcValue);
        }
        else
        {
            calcValue -= 8;
            this.Unit += (int)Math.Pow(2, calcValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and if its even possible to get to the origin three values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mask and shift. You've already got a comment describing the format:

```
// Message identifiers are constructed:         
// Unit Type                    Bit 8-10
// Board ID                     Bit 5-7
// Unit Specific Message Ids    Bit 0-4
```

So the reversal code is:

```
int messageId = identifier & 0x1f;
int boardId = (identifier >> 5) & 7;
int unitType = (identifier >> 8) & 7;
```

Here 0x1f is 11111 in binary - so "anding" with that just leaves the bottom 5 bits. 7 is 111 in binary - so "anding" with that just leaves the bottom 3 bits, which is what you want from `identifier` for `boardId` and `unitType` after you've shift the values a bit.

If you're still slightly confused about how that works, I suggest you try some values on paper, showing everything in binary - start with a message ID, board ID and unit type, construct your identifier (possibly drawing lines between the different parts of the number) and then see what happens when you apply the shifting/masking as above.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. Yes I'm a little bit confused but I'll do the paper trick!